# 1990's videogame with video cutscene of killer bees attacking village

Tags: story-identification, video-games

This may not be enough to go off, but I have been searching for a video game I played a demo of in the 90's.

My only memory is a cut-scene, I think to introduce the game, of (I think) killer bees descending on a village in a green, forested environment. The cut-scene was from the point of view of the bees/attacking creatures, and you could see people in the village scattering as the attackers descended and reached it.

My memory is very vague, so it's highly likely I'm mixing elements. I just wanted to see if there's an obvious candidate.

Comment: Were they definitely bees, or could they have been wasps? And were they normal-sized? Did they only appear in a cut scene, or did you then have to fight them or deal with them in some way?

Comment: (This is not just me being a pedantic entomologist; I vaguely remember a game that featured a fight with giant wasps which was used as part of a regular call-in competition on 90s Saturday morning television; if the cut-scene was followed by a fight with giant wasps it might be worth looking up...)

Comment: I know my description was quite vague; however what I included in the description was the extent of what I could remember; I would've preferred to give more detail! I believe though that Ludo21South's answer below is correct

Comment: No problem, that's understood - but I assumed if you remembered the cut-scene you'd remember if they were normal-sized or six foot high

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to go with [Entomorph: Plague of the Darkfall.](https://www.mobygames.com/game/world-of-aden-entomorph-plague-of-the-darkfall)

This has the jungle environment and the intro is a scene displaying a swarm of bees trying to invade a village, as can be seen in this clip:
[Entomorph intro scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxR31s0EdcI&ab_channel=MickTheMage).

Comment: Hey! Good answer. could you add some more details (such as maybe the video of the cut-scene you mention)? It might be on YouTube or some other sites.

Comment: Wow, well done on very little info! It's so different from the memory in my mind's eye, but I'm sure that's it. Thank you!

Comment: That was a game with what seemed like a lot of potential, but it was a real disappointment.

Comment: Glad I could help. I got triggered by the bees cutscene, mostly because this game was the first one I bought on CDROM from my own money so I have seen that cutscene alot. Also @Buzz: I agree, it was pretty disappointing.